# Two seperate discount amount is not added correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I noticed some weird problem in my cart with discount.

I applied two discounts in my cart. One is for online payment, i.e. 10% and another one is for coupon i.e. 5%. So when I applied these two discounts separately everything works fine. But when both discounts applied together, then there is difference of 0.5%. I mean 10+5=15 i.e. total discount should apply to my cart is 15%, but only 14.5% is reflected in my cart. Why 0.5% is deducted?

There is no tax and other rule applied on website.

Answer (score 2):

You have asked **WHY** ?

Because first 10% discount then on discounted price it applies 5%.

Let **price is 100**,

so **10% of 100** is **10**
Now **discounted price is 90**.

Now **5% of that price (means 90)** is **4.5**
Now **final price is 85.5**.

Comment: Just Going to give the answer then sees that you already give same answer.

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Yeah... this question is basic mathematics and  as you are more experienced person then me, I would like to see your answers on some difficult (core) questions ;)